# Loading second app into its own namespace - which database will it use?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As the subject says, really.

Assume I have two apps, namespaced as `App_A` and `App_B`. `App_A` has `App_B` imported as a git submodule and then autoloaded via its `composer.json`.

When I call `App_B\SomeModel->someMethod()` *from an `App_A` controller*, will the model query the database configured in `App_B`'s config files, or will it inherit the config values from `App_A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: it won't inherit App_B's config files.

Expanded answer: `App_A` is loaded with it's config files. You call `App_B\SomeModel::someMethod()` from `App_A`, App_A's configuration will be used. To have two independent applications with 'knowledge' of each others state you would need to define a communication method between the two such as Message Queues(MQ), HTTP, Sockets, Streams etc etc. You would also never import App_B as a submodule of App_A and vice versa unless you're ok with App_*'s classes being used in the context of the loaded application stack.

Another option is to look at the HMVC or Heirarchical MVC pattern. This could possibly give you a solution to this problem without keeping the applications separate. There was a bundle in Laravel 3 enabling HMVC but I haven't looked into it since then as it (imo) is an anti-pattern. I don't know if one exists for Laravel 4 or 5.

Comment: Thanks, David. Not the answer I hoped for, but at least it clears the situation up!